# Location service Turn off Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

My app using `CoreLocation` and app is register for **Background location updates**.

When User turn off **location service** from setting, I want to show `UILocalNotification`.

In **iOS 6.1.3** and lower After **turn off location service** my app is able to run code in background, so I am able to present `UILocalNotification` to user.

But in **iOS 7** Once I turn off location service My app is not able to execute single line of code in Background.

Even In iOS 7 my is register for Background App refresh.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up delegate method and display UILocalNotification if service is disabled:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status;
```

It's called every time user disable/enable location services in settings.
You can also use this method to find out is a location services disabled/enabled

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]
```

I haven't test it but maybe you find it useful.

Comment: I tested with this also. But Once I turn off location service this method also not getting called in iOS 7.

Comment: Have a look on this post [link](http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2011/07/ios-background-location/). I think if you add check for [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] in beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: if the app is in the background it could work.

Comment: In iOS 7 background timer life is near 3 min only. What when user Turn off location servide after this time period?

Comment: In that post in didUpdateToLocation: method there is check is it in the background and if it's the sendBackgroundLocationToServer: is called, which call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:. So the didUpdateToLocation: method is called every time even if it's in background mode for more that 3 min, right?

Comment: what this link have correct only. But If I not received LocationUpdate for 5 min or more time and user stop turn off location service. In this case this approach won't be useful.

Comment: Have you got method didUpdateToLocation: in AppDelegate file? Is it update all the time even if the user put the app to the background and when the app is on the background for more than let's say 10 min?

Comment: I am updating location based on `distaneFilter`. So once I set `distanceFilter` for 3 km and user is not moving anywhere. In this case location updates will not called. No matters whether `didUpdateToLocation` in AppDelegate or any where else.

Answer (score -5):

Add @property (nonatomic,strong) Reachability *internetReachable;

in AppDelegate.h file then,

Add this line of code in AppDelegate.m file in didFinishedLaunching method:

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(NetWorkCheangeNoti:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain]; [internetReachable startNotifier];

Implement that method in AppDelegate.m like:

-(void)NetWorkCheangeNoti:(Reachability *) info
{
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {

```
        NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
    }
        break;

    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        //NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI");
    }
        break;

    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        //NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN!");
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Try This..!!

Comment: This answer is out of the box. Question is about location services not about internet,

Comment: what do you want to say? is it reverent to location?